# is it possible to replace the cryptography and public key algorithms in Bitcoin?

Tags: hash, blockchain-fork, public-key, cryptography

Is it possible to replace the cryptographic algorithms used in Bitcoin, such as the hash algorithms and the elliptic curve public key cryptography?

Does this require a soft fork or a hard fork?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to replace the cryptographic algorithms used in Bitcoin, such as the hash algorithms and the elliptic curve public key cryptography in Bitcoin?

Yes.

> Does this require a soft fork or a hard fork?

It'll definitely be a hard fork since older clients will not be able to process the new transactions that require different cryptographic algorithms, especially sighashing.

Comment: Is it possible to have new type of transactions like segwit with soft fork and anyone can spend outputs for backwards compatibility?